# Permitir caracteres especiales en htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

¿Cómo puedo permitir caracteres especiales en htaccess? Estoy usando:

```
RewriteRule ^Juegos/Xbox-One/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/ single.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

Sin embargo letras como la ñ o palabras acentuadas hacen que la URL no funcione. También estoy teniendo un problema con ese signo: `-`

El ejemplo de URL para este caso es el siguiente: `Juegos/Xbox-One/1189/Rocket-League-–-Crate-Unlock-Key-x5/`

He intentado sustituirlo en PHP usando el siguiente código:

```
function limpia_url ($juego) {
$titulo_limpio =  preg_replace('~[\\\\/:*?"<>|]~', '', $juego);
$titulo_limpio = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|'), '', $titulo_limpio);
$titulo_limpio = str_replace("-","",$titulo_limpio); //aquí debería eliminarme el carácter, pero no lo hace
$titulo_limpio = str_replace(",","-",$titulo_limpio);
$titulo_limpio = str_replace("'","",$titulo_limpio);
$titulo_limpio = str_replace(" ","-",$titulo_limpio);

return $titulo_limpio;
```

}

Lo único que se me ocurre es que ya que no puedo quitarlo, permitirlo en htaccess. En el caso de los acentos, quizás sería mejor sustituirlos por la vocal correspondiente sin acento.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de la expresión regular `[a-z]` no están las vocales acentuadas ni la ñ.

Por desgracia ni siquiera en el grupo `\w` que es un alias de `[a-zA-z_]` tampoco están las letras acentuadas.

Por lo que tienes que añadir dichos símbolos individualmente en la expresión regular a no ser que utilices el comodín `.` que representa a cualquier carácter

El símbolo `-` se utiliza para definir rangos por lo que es un carácter especial y tiene que ser escapado con una `\`

El RewriteRule que necesitas sería algo tal que así:

```
RewriteRule ^Juegos/Xbox-One/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]+)/ single.php?ID=$1 [L]
```